# Linking static and dynamic libraries on LINUX

Tags: linux, compilation, g++

I am trying to build an executable from different libraries using the below statement

`g++  -fPIC -O -DUSING_PCH -D_REENTRANT -I"/app1/home1/quickfast/boost_1_61_0/include/boost-1_61" -I"/app1/home1/quickfast/boost_1_61_0/." -I"../../src" -I"../src/Examples" -I"/app1/home1/quickfast/boost_1_61_0/include" -L"." -L"/app1/home1/quickfast/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib" -L/app1/home1/quickfast/quickfast-master/lib -l"QuickFAST" -l"boost_thread-gcc44-mt-1_61" -l"boost_system-gcc44-mt-1_61" -l"boost_filesystem-gcc44-mt-1_61" -l"boost_unit_test_framework-gcc44-mt-1_61" -static -ldl  -lpthread -o "../../bin/testSequences"`

The above compilation statement includes lot of libraries, which are availabe as dynamic libaries(.so file) as well as static libraries (.a file). For example library boost_system-gcc44-mt-1_61 is present in the system as libboost_system-gcc44-mt-1_61.so as well as libboost_system-gcc44-mt-1_61.a . What I want is that while compilation only dynamic libraries (.so files) are picked up and static libraries are ignored. Can someone please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling it to pick up static libraries by using the `-static` [link option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).  If you remove it, it'll probably work as you expect.

Comment: Yes, I meant `-static` and have edited the answer to reflect that.  Thanks @MikeKinghan.